# I have python file name MiscTest.py and now I want to run this file in linux with single name MiscTest only

Tags: python, linux

I am new in python and I have python file name MiscTest.py and now I want to run this file in linux with single name MiscTest only not traditional way like python MiscTest.py.

Can anybody have any idea and also I don't want to right shell script for this ? I know I can do it with shell script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you have to make the script executable:

```
chmod +x MiscTest.py
```

Next, add this in the first line (the ["shebang"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)) of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

And make sure that inside the script the execution starts in here (think of this block of code as the `main()` function in C-like languages):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # call main function
```

Also, if you need to execute the script from anywhere in the system (without changing directories), don't forget to add the path of the script to the `$PATH` environment variable of your shell, see this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) for details.

By doing all of the above, you won't have to call the script like `python MiscTest.py`, it'll be enough to say `MiscTest.py` in the shell, or to double-click it in a file explorer. As a side note, although you *can*, I believe you shouldn't remove the `.py` extension of the file, that's how it's recognized as a Python file by the different tools and programs in your system.

Comment: Good answer, except the last sentence. There are plenty of good reasons to remove the `.py` at the end. Does your system have scripts named `pip`, `ipython`, and so on, or `pip.py`, `ipython.py`, etc.?

Comment: thanks @Oscar.                                                                                                                                       I want something like single command only e:g in linux we have top. So is there any other way ?

Comment: Linux itself would not use the file extension for anything; it's decorative. A window manager or desktop environment might use it to associate the file with a particular editor if you were to double-click on the file, but otherwise the extension is meaningless.

Comment: @abarnert No my python script name is MiscTest.py .

Comment: @user2510115 I believe that the extension should be preserved, it'll be easier to edit, identify, etc. by other tools in the system. But as has been pointed out, you can simply rename the file and omit the `.py` extension, it'll work as any other command, as long as the above instructions are followed.

Comment: ok. do you guys have any idea then how top command is executed with just single name top ?

Comment: @user2510115: The same way as anything else: It's named `top`, it's marked executable, it's either a binary ELF program or a script with an appropriate shebang line, and it's on your `$PATH`.

Comment: @user2510115 I see what you mean. Well, additionally you have to add the path of the command to the $PATH environment variable, take a look at this [post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)

Comment: @user2510115: Or, instead of adding a new path to the `PATH` variable, just copy your script into some standard place that's already there, like `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin`. In fact, you may want to look at the `install` command, which is typically used to do the `chmod` from this answer and the copy (and possibly other auxilliary stuff) all together.

Comment: @abarnert: so how can i do the same thing with my script . because still there is ./MiscTest and I also want to remove ./ . Thanks

Comment: @user2510115: Read the last two comments. Óscar explains one way to do it, I explain another. Either one will work.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: You might want to put an explanation about the `PATH` into the answer. If the OP needs that, maybe future searches will as well.

Comment: @abarnert yep, I did just that

Comment: @ÓscarLópez and abarnert guys can you have look on the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945971/python-issue-with-curses-intscr if you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

To chmod the "MiscTest.py" file so that the owner can read, write, and execute the file, the group can read and execute the file, and the world can execute the file, issue the following command:

```
chmod 751 ~/MiscTest.py
```