# Formatting text to fit within a box in Python/Curses

Tags: python-3.x, python-curses

Please advise someone how to fix a text panel in curses?

My bad result

```
----- Panel ------
| Lorem ipsum dol
or sit amet consec
tet uer metus nec 
eu C urabitur elei
fen.             |
|                |
------------------
```

I want the result

```
----- Panel ------
| Lorem ipsum do | 
| lor sit amet   |
| consectet uer  |
| metus nec eu C |
| urabitur       |
| eleifen.       |
------------------
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python issue with curses.intscr()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945971/python-issue-with-curses-intscr)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
from __future__ import division #You don't need this in Python3
from math import *
string = "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
columns = 5
rows = int(ceil(len(string)/columns))
for row in range(1,rows+1):
    panel.addstr(row,1,string[(row*columns)-columns:row*columns])
```

The result of this is:

```
01234
56789
01234
56789
01234
56789
01234
56789
```

Here is a `python-curses` example:

```
from __future__ import division  #You don't need this in Python3
import curses
from math import *

screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
curses.start_color()
screen.keypad( 1 )
curses.init_pair(1,curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_CYAN)
highlightText = curses.color_pair( 1 )
normalText = curses.A_NORMAL
screen.border( 0 )
curses.curs_set( 0 )
columns = 5
string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer metus nec eu C urabitur eleifen."
screen.addstr(1,1,string)
screen.addstr(20,1,"Press ESC to EXIT")
screen.refresh()
rows = int(ceil(len(string)/columns))
box = curses.newwin(rows + 2, columns + 2, 3, 1)
box.box()
for row in range(1,rows+1):
    box.addstr(row,1,string[(row*columns)-columns:(row*columns)])
    box.refresh()

x = screen.getch()
while x != 27:
    x = screen.getch()
curses.endwin()
exit()
```

[image: Screenshot of the code..]